# How to fix Findbugs HTTP parameter directly written to HTTP header output

Tags: java, spring, findbugs

I have a class RequestFilter and @Override methods doFilterInternal. And when i add Header for response, findbugs show error HTTP parameter directly written to HTTP header output. So how can i fix this problem? Thanks all.

```
String rqHd = request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers");    
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", rqHd); // findbugs error here
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is HRS_REQUEST_PARAMETER_TO_HTTP_HEADER error, and you can fix it like that:

```
String rqHd = request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers"); 
if(rqHd != null){
    String rqHeader = URLEncoder.encode(rqHd,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());   
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", rqHeader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch out if you wan't to set ETag header.
ETag looks like W/"myetagvalue"

```
String etagHd = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.ETAG);    
response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ETAG,  URLEncoder.encode(etagHd,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
```

Will be encoded `W%2F%22myetagvalue%22`
 be carefull !